# Special Characters in angular.element

Tags: html, angularjs

My HTML has a div with id="chart_100%views". When I say angular.element("#chart_100%views"), I get the following error

[image: The app gives this error]

I am using angularJS 1.5.8. It works when special characters are removed. Is there a way to get around with special characters?

Comment: Share your code.

Comment: Having special chars in your id or name attribute is not good choice, it will give you hard time later on in readability and maintainability. I feel you need to change the variable naming convention.

Comment: @Hany, the divs actually get created dynamically using column names from the database. All this time, there was a grammar to not let column names in DB to have special characters. The requirement changed and hence the quick fix. However, what are the other ways to handle this? I could map and unmap everytime I interact with the DB but it seems to be kinda messy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

angular.element(), used JQlite behind the scene, SO if you are trying to access an element which has "ID" with special character, then it will fail for sure.

Solution to your question is :

```
var test = document.getElementById('chart_100%views');

console.log( angular.element(test) );
```

Comment: if it worked, can you please mark this answer and answered. thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You may try the Uni-corn( unicode ) for this: `id="chart-100&#37views"`, hope it help !

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use the JQuery function escapeSelector()

> angular.element("#" + $.escapeSelector("chart_100%views"));

Answer (score 0):

```js
$("#" + $.escapeSelector("#text"))
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).